# Querying XML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xquery

I'm at a loss as to how to go about querying an XML file using Javascript.  It's possible this isn't something XML is really suited for (i know a fully featured database might be a better option).  I've looked into tools like XQuery, but I don't know how or if this is something I can use.  Do browsers support XQuery?  Can I write XQuery statements in Javascript files in such a way that I can use the results in other javascript functions? Any help would be appreciated.
Here is some context:

```
$.ajax({

    url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/test.json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (parsed_json) {
        //do stuff with json file
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "weather_map.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            var value = $(xml).find('condition[name="Clear"]').text();
            alert(value);
                    // do stuff with XML file
        }
    });
        //do more stuff with json file
 });
```

Comment: #1 hit on google is http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp. Is there something more specific you are looking to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to process XML in JavaScript is to use jQuery.  This is a very common JavaScript library which can be used to process XML files.  For example

```
var xml = '<students><student name="bob" last="smith"/><student name="john" last="doe"/></students>';
var value = $(xml).find('student[name="bob"]').attr('last');
console.log(value);  // prints: smith
```

Nice Tutorial: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery

Comment: thanks! this was very helpful.  but i appear to be having chrome issues.  i added some context above.  do you have any ideas as to why chrome doesn't approve?

Answer (score 0):

```
for $x in doc("books.xml")/bookstore/book
where $x/price>30
order by $x/title
return $x/title
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_loadxmldoc.asp

Comment: I'm not with or against w3schools.com, it has always been helpful to me though.

Comment: me neither. I discovered that site recently, and I think is pretty important to know that they are not related with w3c in any form

Comment: HTML5 was not also part of w3c ..... so ...does it matter if a tutorial website is part of w3c or not?

Comment: "does it matter if a tutorial website is part of w3c or not?" -> No, it doesn't matter (at least if you are not going to buy a certification from them)

I prefer better sources, like MDN (mozilla). But what you use is up to you.

BTW my comment was just to point that w3schools is known as a site with some bad, old content. Not all of the content is bad, but is a fair warning

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider XQuery in the browser from http://xqib.org?

There is a nice demo there: http://xqueryguestbook.my28msec.com/

Answer (score 0):

E4X support is in some browsers, but I don't know how wide the coverage is.  It's not xquery, but it is a very natural way of processing xml data in javascript.

```
var x=new XML("<root><el>hello, world</el></root>");
alert(x.el);
```

A good guide to E4X is http://rephrase.net/days/07/06/e4x